# Armstrong number program in C++ does not print the correct output

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, pow

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int num,count,temp,sum=0,powr,rem;
    cin>>num;
    temp=num;
    while(temp>0){
        ++count;
        temp=temp/10;
    }
    while(num>0){
        int num;
        rem=num%10;
        powr=round(pow(rem,count));
        sum+=powr;
        num=num/10;
    }
    if(sum==num){cout<<"true";}
    else
    cout<<"false";

    return 0;
}
```

This code only prints false for some reason but never true, and I've tried running through it with a debugger and it correctly calculates the value of sum variable but, after that ultimately always prints false despite the sum being equal to the number input by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of Armstrong number is correct i.e. sum of `pow` of digits where `pow = count of digits`.

However, the problem comes in the last while loop. The control moves out the while loop when `num equals to zero`. And then in the statement

```
if(sum==num){cout<<"true";}
```

you are comparing simply `sum == 0` which obviously comes false .

##### Solution :

Just simply take another variable like `temp2 = num` and compare it finally in the end.

##### Code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int num,count,temp,temp2,sum=0,powr,rem;
    cin>>num;
    temp=num;
    
    temp2 = num;
    
    while(temp>0){
        ++count;
        temp=temp/10;
    }
    while(num>0){

        rem=num%10;
        powr=round(pow(rem,count));
        sum+=powr;
        num=num/10;
    }
    if(sum==temp2){cout<<"true";}
    else
    cout<<"false";

    return 0;
}
```

Hope you find it fruitful!

Answer (score 0):

in the second while loop your num variable equates to zero at the end of all iterations of while. and you are equating zero to the sum in if statement so it will always print false.
thanks hope you will get it

Comment: figured it out i was using the std::count function accidentally as the name of the variable. but your explanation is completely incorrect.

Comment: ok bro you know well please read again hope it helps